# PhotoView - Keep zoom and the xy coordinates

Tags: android, coordinates, zooming, picasso, android-photoview

I am using [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) on my Android application. I want to toggle two images by clicking a button, keeping the zoom and the xy coordinates. I can keep the zoom, but it is hard to keep the xy coordinates because two images have different resolutions and I have to keep the relative xy coordinates *AFTER* the zoom. When I toggle to a new image, if I don't keep the xy coordinates, the zoomed image is always at the center. Below is my current code, which only implements keeping the zoom.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // ... some basic stuffs here

    mRequestCreator1 = Picasso.get().load(mImageUri1);
    mRequestCreator2 = Picasso.get().load(mImageUri2);
    mRequestCreator1.into(mPhotoView);

    mBtnSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final float prevScale = mPhotoView.getScale();
            // MUST use the callback because of timing issue.
            Callback callback = new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() { mPhotoView.setScale(prevScale); }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            };

            if(sPrevIsOriginal) {
                mRequestCreator2.into(mPhotoView, callback);
            } else {
                mRequestCreator1.into(mPhotoView, callback);
            }
            sPrevIsOriginal = !sPrevIsOriginal;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trials and errors, I found out how to do it. You have to get the supplementary matrix of the previous image by using `getSuppMatrix()`, and then apply that supplementary matrix to the new image by using `setSuppMatrix()`. It's important to use supplementary matrix. NEVER try to do this by manipulating `getImageMatrix()` or `getDisplayMatrix()`, cause it either will not work or the code will become a lot more complex.

Comment: @SvenJacobs My pleasure!